# We know there are only one $g \in G$ ($g$ is not identity) which $gH \subseteq Hg$. Bring an example in which $H$ is not normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$(G,*)$ is a group, and $(H,*)$ is a subgroup of G.
We know there are **only one** $g \in G$ ($g$ is not identity) which $gH \subseteq Hg$.

Bring an example in which $gH \neq Hg$ (which means $H$ is not normal)

My thoughts: if $|H|<\infty$ then we know $|gH|=|Hg|$ and using $gH \subseteq Hg$ we can conclude $gH = Hg$ hence $H$ is normal. so to bring an example $|H|$ must be infinite therefor $|G|$ must be infinite too.

Comment: For $H$ to be normal we need $gH\subseteq Hg$ _for all_ $g$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Yes, that's one of the equivalent conditions of $H$ being normal.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible: we can always choose the identity element as $g$, obtaining $gH\subseteq Hg$ and $gH=Hg$.

Comment: Yes, that's totally right. I'm gonna edit my question because I wanted "g" to be non-identity.

Answer (score 1):

Your thoughts are off a little.

You need look no further than $S_3$.  Consider $H=\langle(12)\rangle$.  Only for $g=(12)$ do we have $gH\subseteq Hg$.  And $H$ is easily seen not to be normal.

Comment: I'm sure you're right and my thoughts must be off because of my knowledge ^ب^  I'm new to the subject so I really don't know what S3 and ⟨⟩ means. can you please tell me what's wrong with my conclusion and if you may leave a source to read about S3.

Comment: I like Fraleigh alot.  It's a good introductory text.

Comment: Thank you very much!